# Why Invalid session most of the times https://developer.uber.com/dashboard#_

Tags: uber-api

Uber developer dashabord show error "Invalid session" every time.

After login "https://developer.uber.com/dashboard#_" page show only Invalid session text, I can't do anything.

Any one why this happens?

Comment: Can you try opening that link without a session and logging in again? (By using Incognito Mode / Private Browsing / Private Mode / InPrivate Browsing.) Then log yourself out and try again with a regular session. If that doesn't work, I'd try deleting my cookies developer.uber.com.

Comment: I got the issue, uber has blocked the user with i was trying to login. Uber could better handle such issue on UI.

Comment: Clear your browser's cache or retry in a private window where all the plugins are disabled. Make sure you don't have plugins that might interfere with the JavaScript from the page. Try in a different browser or from a different device or from a different network. Lather, rinse, repeat.